# How to echo the > char in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I insert the > character into an echo message?

I want to have this:

```
echo C:\Users\%uname%>
```

But it doesn't work. NP++ shows me the > symbol in red, so it is something special? The Unicode › symbol also doesn't work. It just displays this: ø symbol.

Comment: No it isn't. MC ND already gave me the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`><|&` are special characters in batch files, but you can escape special characters using `^`

```
echo C:\Users\%uname%^>
```